# How can I add One class's 2 objects and output as combined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Here's what I tried:

```
class Juice:
    def __init__(self, name, capacity):
        self.name = name
        self.capacity = capacity

    def __add__(self,other):
        return (self.capacity+other.capacity)
```

Here I used only add method..

```
    def __add__(self, other):
        return (self.name+"&"+other.name)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.name + ' ('+str(self.capacity)+'L)')


a = Juice('Orange', 1.5)
b = Juice('Apple', 2.0)

result = a + b
print(result)
```

I should have like: Orange&Apple(3.5L)

Comment: you want `a + b` to give you the output `3.5` or `Orange&Apple(3.5L)` ??

Comment: It should be Orange&Apple(3.5L) output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__str__()` method you wrote is executed when you run `print()` or `str()` on one instance.
When you added `a` and `b` the variable `result` has the value `3.5` so when you print it, it will print `3.5`.
What you can do is change the `__add__()` method so that it returns the format you want.

In this solution I used fstrings to print the format of text you want from the `__add__()` method. like this:

```py
class Juice:
    def __init__(self, name, capacity):
        self.name = name
        self.capacity = capacity

    def __add__(self, other):
        return f"{self.name}&{other.name}({self.capacity + other.capacity}L)"


a = Juice("Orange", 1.5)
b = Juice("Apple", 2.0)
print(a + b)
```

this should output

```py
Orange&Apple(3.5L)
```